# Hadoop: Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a random job, but when it get 4 jobs failed, it fails the job:

`Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0`

I tried a lot of times but every 4 fails my job fails, all tasks get killed.
Any option to change this number of fails allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when the SAME map fails 4 time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these parameters to change the failure threshold in mapred-site.xml file:

```
mapreduce.map.maxattempts
mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts
```

It is also possible to ignore failed tasks, these paramteres say that the threshold of failed tasks:

```
mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent
mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent
```